# 表のデータをプログラムで表すスマートな書き方を教えて下さい。

Tags: php, array

`test.com/hogehoge/?yoko=2&tate=3`のようにURLパラメーターから2つの値を受け取ります。

添付画像のように受け取った2つの値(タテ・ヨコ)から、参照されるデータを突き止めます。
仮に横が2縦が3でしたら"1,2,3"がほしいわけです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（求めた数字はまた次の処理に使いますが、一旦関係ないので気にしなくていいです。）

この時どういうやり方で求めたい値を返すのがスマートなのか悩みました。

①if文で縦が〇&横が△のとき～　でやる

```php
<?php
  $result = null;
  if($yoko == 1 && 1 <= $tate && $tate <= 3) $result = array(1,2);
  else if($yoko == 2 && 1 <= $tate && $tate <= 3) $result = array(1,2,3);
  else if(1 <= $yoko && $yoko <= 3 && 1 <= $tate && $tate <= 4) $result = array(2,3);
  #続く
?>
```

表と同じように配列で用意する

```php
<?php
  $data = array(
    array(array(1,2),array(1,2,3),array(2,3),array(2,3,4),array(2,3,4),array(3,4,5),array(4,5),array(4,5,6),array(4,5,6)),
    array(array(1,2),array(1,2,3),array(2,3),array(2,3,4),array(2,3,4),array(3,4,5),array(4,5),array(4,5,6),array(4,5,6))
    #続く
  ),

  $result = $data[$yoko - 1][$tate - 1];
?>
```

その他switch文や連想配列などなど...

上記のような書き方で書いてみましたが、あまり賢い書き方に思えずモヤモヤしたので質問しました。
なにか良い書き方があれば教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 前提の話ですが、PHPではなくてJavascriptやCSSで実施しても良いですか？装飾の部類なので、サーバサイドでやるよりフロントエンドでやることも考えたほうが良いかなと思いまして、

Comment: JSでやることも不可能ではないですが、・パラメーターを文字列として受け取って分解しないと行けない事、DOMがない場所に生成するところなどが個人的にあまり好きではなく...。第三者がHTML(PHP)ファイルを見ただけだと分からないというのがどうかなという感じです。パフォーマンス的にはどうなんでしょう？

Comment: jsでやることも少し考えましたが、そもそもソースコードが丸見えになってしまうのは社内的によくなさそうなので(難読化などもしないので)、PHPでの質問とさせていただければと思います。

Comment: 1. パラメータとしてはどのような形式で受け取ることを想定していますか？ / 2. 表のサイズは 固定 or 可変 のどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 質問にあるカラフルな表は、どのように読むのですか？　読めないデータの可読性を話題にされても、判らないです。

Comment: すみませ、質問の意図をうまく伝えられていないみたいです。

Comment: 質問修正させていただきました。HTMLで表が出したいとかではなく、単純に2つの値から1つの値を求めたいのです。そのときに添付画像に書いてある通り縦と横で決まる値を求めたい、問題なく動くコードは書けるが何か気に入らないので別のいい方法は無いだろうか、ということでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず前提条件として、今回の表をデータ化してということなので、データ構造の問題となります。
PHPはデータ構造ではなく、アルゴリズムを扱うことが得意な言語です。
そのため、いかにきれいにスマートにといってもPHPではあまりきれいにならないという前提に立つ必要があります。

表形式のデータ構造をきれいに整理して扱いやすく管理するには、XMLやjsonやCSVなどの構造化された文書を利用することが最もよいでしょう。今後の保守を考えるとそれらを使うことを検討してみてください。
システムから修正する要件があるのであれば、それこそDBなども利用することも考えたほうが良いでしょう。

それでもPHPで表形式をデータ構造で利用したい場合は配列を使うことが多いと思います。
アクセスがしやすいですし、IFと違って変更に耐えうる形になるでしょう。
あとは可読性の問題なだけかと思っています。となると私でしたらコメントなどを駆使してそれなりにきれいにしますかね。

```
$map = [
/*  *            0,       1,       2,       3,       4,       5,      6,       7,       8, */
    0 => [   "1,2", "1,2,3",   "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,5",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
    1 => [   "1,2", "1,2,3",   "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,5",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
    2 => [   "1,2", "1,2,3",   "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,5",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
    3 => [   "2,3",   "2,3",   "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,5",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
    4 => [   "3,4",   "3,4",   "3,4",   "3,4",   "3,4",   "3,4",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
    5 => [   "1,2", "1,2,3",   "2,3", "2,3,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,5",   "4,5", "4,5,6", "4,5,6"],
                                       /*中略*/
]
```

それでもあまりやりたくはないですね。私だったらJSONもしくはDBで構造化してしまって、それをPHPで参照する方法をとるでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かに配列で用意するならCSVに切り分けて読み込んだほうが良さそうです。